Is it possible to update applet priviliges after install for install?
I want to assign Final Application privilege to an applet.
My card GlobalPlatform version is 2.2.1. I saw this in GPC 2.2.1 specification:

The Final Application privilege is by default assigned to the Issuer
Security Domain. It may be reassigned only if the Issuer Security
Domain has the Final Application privilege;

1- I want to know is it possible to update privileges of an applet after its installation (E.g. assign Final application privilege to an applet after its install)? Or is it possible to update ISD/SSD privileges?
2- Should Java Card applet has specific functionality to allow it to be Final Application? I mean that if I want to assign Final Application privilege to it during Install for Install should the applet has some built-in functionalities in it?

For 1.: I've never seen this happen and I don't think it is possible for this version. 2. no, I've never seen this and it would not make that much sense. I don't even think there is read access let alone write access. But as I'm not 100% and the GP specs are rather large and not that well organized - at least not for me - I'll not write a (late) answer.
